# What is this jutting structure in the tail section called and what is its function?

Tags: military, fighter, feature-identification, tail

I was wondering if there is a name for this particular structure on Su-27 and F-22 and if they serve any function?

[image: su-27]

[image: f-22]

Comment: re: the F22 part: [What is this little "rod" thing on the back of the F-22 for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/101790) has an answer with a detailed F22 diagram.

Answer (score 3):

On the SU-27 that is where the rear fire control radar is housed. On the F-22 it is the runaway arrestor hook housing.

Comment: runaway arrestor ? Like some kind of Blade Runner ?

Comment: @Jeffrey Ever seen the ramps on highways for runaway trucks whose brakes have failed? Similar concept. On a military runway you install something like this https://www.safran-group.com/products-services/emergency-arresting-systems-military-aircraft so aircraft whose brakes have failed and don't have any other means of slowing down other than an arrestor hook can safely come to a stop. And yes, something like a blade runner. :)

Comment: @JuanJimenez, do you have a reference for the Su-27 rear fire control radar? I'm curious about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Tyler I did a little more research and I think it may be the radar illumination warning system component of the fire control system, and I am not even sure if that wording is correct. There is an SPO-15 Beryoza system for that with an indicator in the cockpit (on the bottom right hand side of the instrument panel), and I think I found that the rear boom also contains the chaff dispensing system. The info I found suggests it is also used in the Mig-29 and Chinese J-11. I am not really an expert on this, I just digged up the best info I could find.